# How to install a WP-eCommerce plugin from WordPress Plugin Directory, placing the plugin in a specific folder?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm developing an extension for [WPeCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-e-commerce/). This extension is a payment gateway, which needs to have its sources inside **[WordPressRootDir]/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-merchants**.

Everything is working well until I've tried to create a product page in [WordPress Plugin Directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/). As plugins are installed into **[WordPressRootDir]/wp-content/plugins/** they aren't recognized by WpeCommerce.

Is there a way to install a plugin from WordPress Plugin Directory, placing the plugin in a specific folder?